# Создание массива для использования в Generics

Tags: java, c#, generics

Чисто академический интерес. Читаю книгу Роберта Седжвика "Алгоритмы на Java". В его книге есть пример (листинг 1.3.5). Стек реализован в виде обобщенной коллекции (`Generics`). В основе хранилища лежит массив.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
public class ResizingArrayStack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
{
    private Item[] a = (Item[]) new Object[1];
    ....
}
```

Как создать подобный массив на С#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C# всё ещё проще:

```
public class ResizingArrayStack<Item> : IEnumerable<Item>
{
     private Item[] a = new Item[1];
}
```

Разница состоит в том, что у C# генерик-типы *реифицированы* (то есть, существуют реально во время выполнения), а значит, можно создать массив типа, являющегося генерик-аргументом. В Java такого нельзя, и приходится идти на трюки.

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо!

Comment: @user: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Только не `implements` а `:`

Comment: Да понятно, я ж запускал уже :)

Comment: @Vlad: Угу, и тогда уж `IEnumerable`.